# Myth or Fact? U.K pilots struggling for work while U.S big airlines are kicking down the door for pilots with an American passport

Tags: flight-training

Myth or Fact? Why are U.K/British pilots struggling to find their first job, then once they get the hours are still struggling? The question Is... Is it easier to get a job being a American Aviator Or British Aviator. For Aviation

There are even TV Shows about pilots having to travel across the world just to find work with a British passport. Worst Place To Be A Pilot - Season 1 / Episode 3 - Full Episode

Meanwhile, CNN posted an article that U.S American pilots are in heavy demand and big companies are practically kicking down the door for new pilots. I list my sources so you know what I'm talking about.

Is it a fact that U.S student pilots are having trouble paying for training with the U.S economy or is it because there are harsher rules for Americans so now less people are meeting the requirements? Are older pilots retiring? etc.

[image]
 I would hyper link but I don't have enough reputation points

Comment: Here are the sources-------[link] (http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/d7117f1e-d963-11e5-a72f-1e7744c66818.html#axzz46uLwU7s4)  (http://learningenglish.voanews.com/content/us-pilot-shortage/3229183.html) (http://money.cnn.com/2016/03/07/pf/jetblue-pilot-training-program/)

Comment: US requires 1500 hours for the first officer. And that is a crazy amount of hours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the it's about commenting broad news and corporate communication rather than an actual question. Rework it so that this is an actual question.

Comment: Sounds like this would be a better fit on [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), any way

Comment: Cathay Pacific and Dragonair have offered free pilot training for those who has no experience for a long period.